# Model from view not given to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the problem that the model in this controller is null (everything in it). So from the viewpage the model is incorrectly filled. So when the application arrives at the controller, the model is empty (everything is null).

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Product Beheer";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout3.cshtml";
}
@model IntroSport.Models.ProductToevoegModel
<h2>ProductToevoegen</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ProductMaken", "Admin"))
{
    //@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-label">Prijs</div>
        <div class="editor-field"> 
                                  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.Prijs)</div> 
        <div class="editor-label">Size</div>
        <div class="editor-field"> 
                                  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.Size)</div>
        <div class="editor-label">Merk</div>
        <div class="editor-field"> 
                                  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.Merk)</div>
        <div class="editor-label">Naam</div>
        <div class="editor-field"> 
                                  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.Naam)</div>
        <div class="editor-label">URL Foto</div>
        <div class="editor-field"> 
                                  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.AfbeeldingURL)</div>

        <input type="submit" value="Voeg toe" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ProductMaken()
{
    try
    {
        ProductToevoegModel viewModel = new ProductToevoegModel();
        return View(viewModel);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ViewBag.FoutMelding = "Er is iets fout gegaan: " + e;
        return View();
    }
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProductMaken(ProductToevoegModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            productDBcontroller.maakProduct(model);
            return Redirect("/admin/ProductBeheer");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ViewBag.FoutMelding = "Er is iets fout gegaan: " + e;
            return View();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return View("ProductMaken", model);
    }
```

Model:

```
namespace IntroSport.Models
{
    public class ProductToevoegModel
    {
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Product model:

```
namespace IntroSport.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dit is een verplicht veld!")]
        public String Naam;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dit is een verplicht veld!")]
        public String Size;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dit is een verplicht veld!")]
        public String AfbeeldingURL;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dit is een verplicht veld!")]
        public String Merk;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dit is een verplicht veld!")]
        public int Categorie;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dit is een verplicht veld!")]
        public int Voorraad;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dit is een verplicht veld!")]
        public Double Prijs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change all fields in `Product` class to auto properties:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dit is een verplicht veld!")]
    public String Naam { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dit is een verplicht veld!")]
    public String Size { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dit is een verplicht veld!")]
    public String AfbeeldingURL { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dit is een verplicht veld!")]
    public String Merk { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dit is een verplicht veld!")]
    public int Categorie { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dit is een verplicht veld!")]
    public int Voorraad { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dit is een verplicht veld!")]
    public Double Prijs { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I need to use the ProductToevoegModel because I later want to add a dropbox menu.

Comment: This will not be the problem with such model. Describe the problems.

Comment: The problem is that when I filled in the form and click on submit, the viewModel in the HttpPost action "ProductMaken" is totally empty. So the filled in form is not properly send.

Comment: Aha, so it's about the properties that are not being filled in, but are listed in the Product model? Does this mean I have to create more textfields? Even though the Product_ID in the product model does not need to be known by the user filling this form out. EDIT: I just removed all the required tags.. Stil not working.

Comment: Ok, try also to change all `int` and `double` fields to nullable `int?` and `double?`.

Comment: I now also changed all int and double fields in the models to int? and double?. Still, the model in the action is empty.

Comment: See answer. It was not easy to find :)

Comment: Great! Works now, unbelievable that this caused a lot of frustration haha! Such a simple and basic thing.